# is there a better way to write this if statement in laravel

Tags: laravel, if-statement, eloquent

good day i am new in laravel and i am still learning as i go.

my question is this code works but i feel like it unnecessary and can be written much better please can someone assist would a switch case be better or is there a better way to write this and please explain to me thank you.

debtorscontroller.php

```
    $debtors_created_at = $debtors->created_at;
    $now = Carbon::now();
    $created_at_in_days = $debtors_created_at->diffInDays($now);


     if ($created_at_in_days >= 0 and $created_at_in_days <= 10){

         Debtor::whereId($debtorid)->update(['collection_level' => 'Pre Collection']);
     }elseif ($created_at_in_days >= 11 and $created_at_in_days <= 30){

            Debtor::whereId($debtorid)->update(['collection_level' => 'Collection Level 1']);
        }
     elseif ($created_at_in_days >= 31 and $created_at_in_days <= 60){

         Debtor::whereId($debtorid)->update(['collection_level' => 'Collection Level 2']);
     }
     elseif ($created_at_in_days >= 61){

         Debtor::whereId($debtorid)->update(['collection_level' => 'Collection Level 3']);
     }
```

this just check wheter the debtor was created at and if it is 1-10 days old it changes

its level

days
1-10 is pre collection
11-30 is collection level 1
31-60 is collection level 2
61-90+ is collection level 3

this is a field in my debtors table collection_level

Comment: Bit late but you should avoid using else ifs whenever possible. 

The problem is that it's a lot slower compared to other conditional statements and the normal if statement. Else ifs tend to run through each condition which results in it being slow unlike the normal if statement where it's either true or false and the switch-case statements that have specific values assigned to them.

Comment: @JaphethSuarez - Have you ever disassembled the code generated by if/else and switch statements? CPUs have long had look-ahead and can handle if/else code blocks. Switch statements often are optimized into if/else blocks, some become jump blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use switch statement to do the same -

```
$debtors = Debtor::whereId($debtorid);
$created_at_in_days = $debtors->created_at->diffInDays(Carbon::now());

switch ($created_at_in_days) {
    case $created_at_in_days >= 0 and $created_at_in_days <= 10:
        $debtors->update(['collection_level' => 'Pre Collection']);
        break;
    case $created_at_in_days >= 11 and $created_at_in_days <= 30:
        $debtors->update(['collection_level' => 'Collection Level 1']);
        break;
    case $created_at_in_days >= 31 and $created_at_in_days <= 60:
        $debtors->update(['collection_level' => 'Collection Level 2']);
        break;
    case $created_at_in_days >= 61:
        $debtors->update(['collection_level' => 'Collection Level 3']);
        break;         
    default:
        $debtors = $debtors->get();
```

Comment: thank you would you say the switch case is a better option for this? and why?

Comment: If there are multiple choices implemented through 'if-else', then the speed of the execution will be slow. whereas If we have multiple choices then the switch statement is the best option as the speed of the execution will be much higher than 'if-else'.

Comment: I agree the code looks better/cleaner, but your statement of much faster is incorrect. There will be little to no difference in performance. Switch statements will either generate if/else statements or jump tables. For this example, neither will be substantially faster than the other.